# How to read a text file into a two dymentional dynamic vector in C++?

Tags: c++, linux

I have a text file with two columns and unknown number of lines. So I want to load two columns into a dynamic two dimensional vector. Here is what I have so far, it is not working. If this was one dimensional, I know how to do this. White space separates two columns. Since i am reading 2 columns, I only need 2 vectors of size n.

```
vector<vector<string> > component;
ifstream in_file("/tmp/FW.txt", ios::binary);

//Check if the file is open
if(!in_file.is_open()) 
{
   cout << "File not opened..." << endl;
   exit (1);
}

for(int i=0; !in_file.eof(); i++)
{
   in_file >> component.push_back();  
   //component.push_back(in_file);
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to get this to work? Also If you can tell me how to print the two dimensional vector back, so it looks like original file, that would be nice too. This need to run on Linux(Red hat)

Comment: If you have a known format to determine what constitutes column1 and column2 that makes it easier to parse. You are not `push_back()` or the extraction `>>` operator correctly. I'd suggest also looking at the `read()` method on `std::ifstream`

Comment: Do you want the result to be a size-2 vector of size-n vectors, or a size-n vector of size-2 vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
vector< vector<string> > component;
ifstream in_file("/tmp/FW.txt"); // N.B., not ios::binary since you're reading text strings
vector<string> vs( 2 );
// Assume they are separated by just whitespace
while( in_file >> vs[0] >> vs[1] )
{
    component.push_back( vs );
}
```